# How to use nested upto-loops in an HTML environment for fixtures in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, fixtures

I am preparing a db which for reasons of trial and error is dropped and migrated over and over. In order to save time on creating db-entries I have made use fixtures.

My fixture.yml code looks like this:

```
    <% 1.upto(n) do |i|
         1.upto(m) do |j|
          distance: <%= 1+rand(998) %>
          quantity: <%= 0 %>
         end
     end %>
```

For each connection between i and j I want to introduce a random distance and a zero transportation quantity, as it will be optimized by GAMS anyway. How can I make that work?

These are the error messages I get:

```
    rake aborted!
    (erb):5: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
    distance: <%= 1+rand(998) ; _erbout.concat "\n      quan: "
           ^
    (erb):5: unterminated string meets end of file
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Close your erb tags when you aren't in erb mode.

```
   <% 1.upto(n) do |i|
     1.upto(m) do |j| %>
      distance: <%= 1+rand(998) %>
      quantity: <%= 0 %>
     <% end
 end %>
```